# RVL-CDIP dataset on google colab

Tags: cookies, dataset, google-colaboratory, wget

I am trying to download RVL-CDIP dataset on google colab with this command :

```
!wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate  'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bz1dfcnrpXM-MUt4cHNzUEFXcmc' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=0Bz1dfcnrpXM-MUt4cHNzUEFXcmc" -O rvl-cdip.tar.gz && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
```

But it doesn't download the dataset and it shows :

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘rvl-cdip.tar.gz’

rvl-cdip.tar.gz         [ <=>                ]   3.02K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-11-02 11:40:28 (39.6 MB/s) - ‘rvl-cdip.tar.gz’ saved [3096]
```

Can someone help me to see what is the problem and why it is not loading? I tried it before and it worked but now it doesn't. Thank you

Comment: I ran the command and checked the contests of the `rvl-cdip.tar.gz` file.
It looks like it returns `Google Drive - Quota exceeded` with the description `Too many users have viewed or downloaded this file recently. Please try accessing the file again later. If the file you are trying to access is particularly large or is shared with many people, it may take up to 24 hours to be able to view or download the file. If you still can't access a file after 24 hours, contact your domain administrator`

Comment: @SBB did you manage to unzip it?

Comment: @Alex, no unzipping it takes the whole space in google colab and it won't finish